# Problems with Python 3.7 /Mosquitto

Tags: python, mosquitto

I want to exchange Messages with MQTT over my local network with a Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 and a RasperryPi with Rasperian 10. The broker is running and when I subscribe from the Raspberry via console it works. But when I try to connect to the broker with Python I receive the following error:

```
1622369636: New connection from 192.168.0.11 on port 1883.
1622369636: New client connected from 192.168.0.11 as SMS_Daemon (c1, k60).
1622369636: Sending CONNACK to SMS_Daemon (0, 0)
1622369706: Socket error on client SMS_Daemon, disconnecting.
```

in the logfile of Mosquitto

I had the code from a tutorial and have, when it not worked used code of another tutorial, but received the same error. I found out that Ubuntu 18.04 uses Mosquitto 1.4.15 and on Raspberry 1.5.7. Both versions are from the standard repository.

Here the Python Code.

```
# -*- coding: utf8' -*-
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

mqttTopic = 'RaspberryPi1/SMS_Daemon'

def connect_msg():
    print("Connect to broker")

def publish_msg():
    print("Message published")

mqttClient = mqtt.Client(client_id='SMS_Daemon') 
mqttClient.on_connect = connect_msg 
mqttClient.on_publish = publish_msg 
mqttClient.connect("192.168.0.1",1883)
```

Anyone has an idea where i can search for a solution or where my problem is located?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704632/mqtt-socket-error-on-client-unknown Check answers given here.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't started the MQTT Client loop.

You should add

```
mqttClient.loop_forever()
```

after the last line

Also the code provided won't actually do anything apart from print `Connect to broker`

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem was that i was lost in the new world of messages and after i go deeper in the theme i understood my mistake. Now it works. Case was that there where no parameters on the def's